# how to use chrome.process api to get my chrome extension memory and resource usage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, extension-methods, cpu-usage

Is there a way I programmatically get CPU usage and memory usage for my chrome extension?
I checked few resources on chrome API that I can use chrome.process API to fetch the data, but I am not able to use it in my react app.

```
const fetchExtensionData = async () => {
    const processInfo = await chrome.processes.getProcessInfo({});
    debug_console_log("processes processInfo", processInfo)
};
fetchExtensionData();
```

Here I created the function to get the data, but it is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProcessInfo')
```

How can I get the memory and usage data for my extension??
Or suggest any other method that will work.

Comment: As the documentation says it's only in dev channel of Chrome.

Comment: How can I access the dev channel and that data?
As I want to create a debug page for the developers to check the regular usage of the memory by the extension.

Comment: See [these articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=dev%20channel%20of%20Chrome).